# intellij, ktor, kotlinx serialization (Cannot access 'Serializable': it is internal in 'kotlin.io')

Tags: kotlin, serialization, ktor

Few months before my code was working. now when I got back to it won't work. This is my code:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class ApiResponse(
    val success: Boolean,
    val message: String? = null,
    val prevPage: Int? = null,
    val nextPage: Int? = null,
    val lastUpdated: Long? = null
)
```

Right now serialization part of the import is unresolved reference.

**@Serializable** part when I hover mouse over it I get the following quote:

> This class does not have a constructor.
> Cannot access 'Serializable': it is internal in 'kotlin.io'

These are my gradle plugins and dependencies:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.20"
                id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.7.20"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:2.1.3")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization:2.1.3")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.1.3")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.4")

    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:2.1.3")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlinVersion")

    // Koin for Ktor
    implementation( "io.insert-koin:koin-ktor:$koinVersion")
    implementation( "io.insert-koin:koin-logger-slf4j:$koinVersion")
}
```

Comment: Did you add the serialization plugin in your build definitions?

Comment: If your code can be compiled successfully please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTIJ.

Comment: @AssafShouval I do have the Serialization plugin in my gradle file

Comment: do you get the same error when you compile?

Comment: I do sadly @AssafShouval

Comment: The question is missing some input, what have changed in the last months since it worked? did you change code? project definitions? language update? framework update?

Comment: I dont really recall wel but probably kotlin update @AssafShouval

Comment: Try importing java.io.Serializable instead

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the plugin, you need to declare the dependency. For example:

```
dependencies {

  // serialization
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm
  implementation group: "org.jetbrains.kotlinx", name: "kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm", version: "1.5.1"

…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this dependency and sync the project it'll be good to go

```
dependencies {
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.2")
}
```